# Unable to run the demo setup

Tags: ant, business-process-management, activiti

I have downloaded the Activity 5.10 zip file and then i have downloaded and configured the Apache ANT and i test it and it worked successfully.
But i am unable to run the demo file as specified in this link http://activiti.org/userguide/#demo.setup

if i type the following using the cmd command line:-

```
C:\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\setup>ant demo.start
```

I will get the following error:-

```
'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Can anyone help me in identifying what is the problem?
BR

**:::UPDATE:::**

thanks for the reply, i have copied the ANT bin files inside the setup directory for the activity,, then i run the CMD command again ,, but i got the following error that i build failed,, 
AS MENTIONED BELOW:-

```
C:\Users\Desktop\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\setup>ant demo.start
Buildfile: C:\Users\Desktop\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\setup\build.xml

demo.install:

internal.cfg.create:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Desktop\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.
10\setup\build\activiti-cfg
      [zip] Building zip: C:\Users\Desktop\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\s
etup\build\activiti-cfg.jar
     [echo] copying configuration to ../workspace/activiti-engine-examples/src/m
ain/config
    [unzip] Expanding: C:\Users\Desktop\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\setu
p\build\activiti-cfg.jar into C:\Users\Desktop\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.
10\workspace\activiti-engine-examples\src\main\config

internal.classpath.libs:

internal.taskdef.launch:

h2.start:
     [echo] starting H2 database...
   [launch] launching cmd 'C:\Users\Desktop\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\
apps\h2\h2.start.bat ' in dir 'C:\Users\Desktop\activiti-5.10\activiti-5
.10\apps\h2'
   [launch] waiting for launch completion msg 'TCP server running'...
   [launch]   'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   [launch]   operable program or batch file.
   [launch] launched process completed
     [echo] H2 database started

tomcat.start:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Desktop\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\setup\build.xml:330: couldn
't find executable for script C:\Users\Desktop\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.
10\apps\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\bin\startup

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: Your operating system cannot find the "ant" command. Have you installed ANT? If yes, then you need to add the $ANT_HOME/bin directory to your command path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typed `tomcat.install` and it solved the problem since I need to download the tomcat inside the apps directory.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't set the ant directory in you path variable. Either specifiy the entire path to ant or add it to the path variable